# Can't get a Listview to refresh or remove an item

Tags: java, android, listview, view, android-listview

Here is the code, i don't think it'll be to hard to solve but I've tried all i can!:

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                   R.layout.row, filenames);

            listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

            listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                                        int position, long id) {

                    final String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);



                    final File a = new File(extStorageDirectory
                            + "/Android/data/com.tobin.swag/backups/" + item);

                    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

                    v.vibrate(30);

                    AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(Backups.this);

                    alertbox.setTitle("Pick a new task for " + item);
                    alertbox.setCancelable(true);
                    alertbox.setItems(array, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){

                            if (which == 0) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Uploading to drive is not done, !!>?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                            if (which == 1) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Copying to there is not done yet, FAR OUT !!>?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                            }

                            if (which == 2) {
                             a.delete();
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                listView1.invalidate();
                                listView1.refreshDrawableState();


                            }
```

I either want to remove the item clicked from the listview, or just refresh the listview as the file has been deleted!

Thanks for the help!

Comment: a good start would be to actually remove the item from the ArrayAdapter. you only delete the file

Comment: Agreed, i added `adapter.remove(item)` and it crashes, i think it's because `item` is a string, not an item on the listview. Im not sure how to fix that though.

Comment: that shouldnt be the problem, post the stacktrace please

Answer (score 2):

Try to call invalidate method after notifyDataChange like this :

```
listView1.invalidateViews();
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, I've also tried `adapter.remove(item)` and it crashes :( thanks for the help though!

Comment: Debug and see the log to know the reason for crashing app

Comment: @XavierTobin `adapter.remove(item)` should work. what also should work is `filenames.remove(position); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` if you get an exception there, post it

Answer (score 1):

Use Yourlistview.invalidateViews(). I hope it will help :)

Comment: Still doesn't work, I've also tried `adapter.remove(item)` and it crashes :( thanks for the help though!